# combining two sum results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to view Antivirus events that will show the number of event for the AV and firewall within a 24 hour period. Basically I'm trying to sum the same column under different condition. I've tried using a CASE WHEN statement in the SUM function, but it does not return any results.

```
SELECT 
        events.arc_sourceHostName,
        SUM(CASE WHEN events.arc_deviceEventClassId="fw" THEN events.arc_baseEventCount ELSE 0 END) AS "FWCount",
        SUM(CASE WHEN events.arc_deviceEventClassId="av" THEN events.arc_baseEventCount ELSE 0 END) AS "AVCount"

FROM    events

WHERE
        events.arc_deviceVendor = "BitDefender"
        AND
        (events.arc_deviceEventClassId="fw"
        OR
        events.arc_deviceEventClassId="av")


GROUP BY
        events.arc_sourceHostName

ORDER BY FWCount DESC
```

ADDITIONAL DETAILS

expecting to see the hostname followed by the number of AV event, followed by the number of firewall events.

```
Hostname   AVCount   FWCount
Host1      5         4
Host2      3         5
```

Comment: Did you try to run a count query to see whether there actually are records to retrieve with those 'where' conditions?

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect paste, but that is mostly the corrected version that I tried. Yes I do receive events for the where statement without the sum statement.

Comment: This runs? Why is "arc_deviceEventClassId" named "deviceEventClassId" elsewhere?

Comment: And what tool are you using to run your queries?

Comment: ha yeah it did run, but you are correct. I think I need more coffee today. so so sorry. It returned a page finally with the correction (it was just blank) but no results.

Comment: ArcSight's web interface. I'm going to try this on the back end through the MySQL command line.

Comment: What data type is events.arc_baseEventCount? and can you remove the quotes around the alias at the end of the case?

Comment: Integer. okay so this was completely my fault. I needed to just re-write the whole thing because of so many mistakes. I'm new to MySQL and not use to code where error result in a blank page with no message. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this query do what you want?

```
SELECT e.arc_sourceHostName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN e.arc_deviceEventClassId = 'fw' THEN e.arc_baseEventCount ELSE 0 END) AS FWCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN e.arc_deviceEventClassId = 'av' THEN e.arc_baseEventCount ELSE 0 END) AS AVCount
FROM events e
WHERE e.arc_deviceVendor = 'BitDefender' AND
      e.deviceEventClassId IN ('fw', 'av')
GROUP BY e.arc_sourceHostName
ORDER BY FWCount DESC;
```

If this doesn't work then no rows may meet the `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: Gordon: I get a error when I run your query. "Unable to get case independent query, returning original SQL"

Comment: okay, so after many re-writing everything because I obviously made many mistakes I've managed to get this query to work.